# Detecting Length of Segmented Image in EmguCV C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

**The Requirement** is to measure the distance of Canny Edged images on my program. To be specific the images I'm working on are human feet. I have already done this program via Matlab.

**To do this**, I'm using the Matlab codes as my Algorithm for EmguCV c# code on VS2013.

Here's the Matlab codes that was already converted into C#

```
 A = imread('feet1.jpg');
%// Some pre-processing. Treshold image and dilate it.
level = 0.9;
B = im2bw(A,level);
%// Detect edges
F = edge(B,'Canny');
figure; 
imshow(F);
hold on;   
 %Draw boundaries on Canny Edged image
    for k = 1:length(B),
     boundary = B{k};
     plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'b','LineWidth',2);
    end
```

C#

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName);
                imageBox1.Image = _imgInput;
            }
        }
public void ApplyCanny(double thresh=50.0, double threshLink = 20.0)
    {
        if (_imgInput == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Image<Gray, byte> _imgCanny = new Image<Gray, byte>(_imgInput.Width, _imgInput.Height, new Gray(0));
        _imgCanny = _imgInput.Canny(thresh, threshLink);
        imageBox1.Image = _imgCanny;
    }

#region extract contours
        using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
        {

            for (Contour<Point> contours = _imgCanny.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
            {

                Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.015, storage);
                if (currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Width > 20)
                {
                    CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(color, contours, new MCvScalar(255), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));
                    color.Draw(currentContour.BoundingRectangle, new Bgr(0, 255, 0), 1);
                }
            }

        }
```

The remaining codes that I'm stuck on converting:

```
%Measure boundaries
measurements = regionprops(F, 'Centroid', 'BoundingBox');
centroid = measurements(1).Centroid;
bb = measurements(1).BoundingBox;
y1 = bb(2); % Top of bounding box.
y2 = bb(2)+bb(4);  % Bottom of bounding box.
centroidToToe = y2 - centroid(2);
```

Edit: 9/28/2017 - I can now successfully identify the feet. The last step would be the measurement of the bounding rectangle. I researched some and it would seem like I need to use the method CvMoments.

Comment: It would be better if you post your code here. As your question is very generic, I could not understand the requirement.

Comment: Please show what you've tried - and have a read of [Ask]

Comment: I already added the codes. By the way, just to include. I already tried looking the emgucv example folder, but most of them are stream-based object detection. I'm only leaning towards static image segmentation and the segmented image's measurement.

Comment: did you try findcontours method? or you can use cvblob object with some morpohology filters.

Comment: Hi cagri, I will try that. I will post the feedback here.

Comment: Hi @cagri done with the findcontours method. Im researching about the CvMoments method. Do you have an idea on how to use it?

Comment: @TommieZabala i haven't used it. i am sure you know about it much more than me.